# Can I do a second 'query' on a MongoDB cursor?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, cursor, aggregation-framework

Imagine a collection with about 5,000,000 documents. I need to do a `basicCursor` query to select ~100 documents based on too many fields to index. Let's call this the `basicCursorMatch`. This will be immensely slow.

I can however to a `bTreeCursor` query on a few indexes that will limit my search to ~500 documents. Let's call this query the `bTreeCursorMatch`.

Is there a way I can do this `basicCursorMatch` directly on the cursor or collection resulting from the `bTreeCursorMatch`?

Intuitively I tried

```
var cursor = collection.find(bTreeCursorMatch);
var results = cursor.find(basicCursorMatch);
```

similar to `collection.find(bTreeCursorMatch).find(basicCursorMatch)`, which doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$match: bTreeCursorMatch}, // Uses index 5,000,000 -> 500 fast
    {$match: basicCursorMatch}, // No index, 500 -> 100 'slow'
    {$sort}
]);
```

.. but it seems that I cannot do this either. Is there an alternative to do what I want?

The reason I am asking is because this second query will differ a lot and there is no way I can index all the fields. But I do want to make that first query using a `bTreeCursor`, otherwise querying the whole collection will take forever using a `basicCursor`.

**update**

Also, through user input the subselection of 500 documents will be queried in different ways during a session with an unpredictable `basicCursor` query, using multiple `$in` `$eq` `$gt` `$lt`. But during this, the `bTreeCursor` subselection remains the same. Should I just keep doing both queries for every user query, or is there a more efficient way to keep a `reference` to this collection?

Comment: You can't concatenate queries, because cursors 'live' in the database, they already contain the query and the cursor position. But you can simply append additional criteria *at the end of your query*, or force use of the index.

Comment: Defining an aggregation pipeline with two $match elements works. What error message did you get?

Comment: @Pascal Bugnion seriously? I must have done something wrong then. I will try this again shortly. Will this use the index for the first query? Or will it just merge the queries and use a basic cursor? I was using MongoDB `2.4`, maybe the two $matches needs `3.0`?

Comment: It will use the index if it can. If you pass { explain : true } as the second argument to the call to aggregate, it returns how it's going to do the query, rather than actually performing the query. You'll find that, for each state, there is a 'plan' field which contains 'cursor' information.

Comment: That said, I think you're assuming the MongoDB engine is less clever than it actually is. If you pass a query to `find` where some of the fields have indexes and others don't, it will start by sub-selecting using the appropriate index, and then to a full search on the remaining documents.

Comment: I might try and phrase all of this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you rarely need to run second queries on a cursor. You specially don't need to break MongoDB's work into separate indexable / non-indexable chunks.

If you pass a query to MongoDB's `find` method that can be partially fulfilled by a look-up in an index, MongoDB will do that look-up first, and then do a full scan on the remaining documents.

For instance, I have a collection `users` with documents like:

```
{ _id : 4, gender : "M", ... }
```

There is an index on `_id`, but not on gender. There are ~200M documents in `users`.

To get an idea of what MongoDB is doing under the hood, add `explain()` to your cursor (in the Mongo shell):

```
> db.users.find( { _id : { $gte : 1, $lt : 10 } } ).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor oldId_1_state_1",
    "n" : 9,
    "nscannedObjects" : 9
}
```

I have cut out some of the fields returned by `explain`. Basically, cursor tells you if it's using an index, `n` tells you the number of documents returned by the query and `nscannedObjects` is the number of objects scanned during the query. In this case, mongodb was able to scan exactly the right number of objects.

What happens if we now query on gender as well?

```
> db.users.find( { _id : { $gte : 1, $lt : 10 }, gender : "F" } ).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor oldId_1_state_1",
    "n" : 5,
    "nscannedObjects" : 9
}
```

`find` returns 5 objects, but had to scan 9 documents. It was therefore able to isolate the correct 9 documents using the `_id` field. It then went through all 9 documents and filtered them by gender.

Comment: Thank you. I have upvoted this answer (and previous comments) for now. However I'm not sure if this answer is advanced enough. I would applaud an effort to add a bit more complexity. For example, in reality I often find that `explain` returns 3 or 5 plans and cursors with different indexes. I already use basic explains to verify my queries, but the multiple plans is where it get's confusing. Also, working on a semi-permanent subselection of documents (see edit) is not addressed. E.g. Would you simply merge the two query objects for every "subquery"?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment. Calling `explain` on `find` returns a single plan. If you run `db.collection.find().explain({verbose: true})`, you get an extra sub-document called `allPlans` that contains all the plans that might have applied to the query. The plan that was used is the one at the top-level of the explain document.

Comment: When you run an aggregation with `{ explain : true}`, you get a plan for each stage in the aggregation pipeline (MongoDB also adds the allPlans sub-document, which lists all the plans that were considered for that stage, but the top-level plan is the one that was actually executed).

Comment: Imagine the first `$match` taking a second. Then imagine you want to do a `$group` in order to count fields of all documents. Next, you want to do a second `$match` separate from `$group`. This is where you need to do a second query, because both pipelines share the same initial query. Ideally, you want to perform the `$group` and second independent `$match` in parallel on the first `$match` in order to safe one second. But afaik that's not possible, so we do the whole initial match two times.